# Windows 10 can't connect to Ubuntu on Virtualbox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, firewall

I installed VirtualBox 5.0.4 on Windows 10 Home. And I install Ubuntu 15.04 on the Virtualbox with the virtualbox network set to Bridge mode. The host(Windows) can't ping to the guest (Ubuntu) and vice versa. Strangely other computers can ping to the Ubuntu virtual machine and the Windows machine. So the problem is only between the host and the guest.

I disabled the Windows firewall and defender.

My purpose is that I develop websites in the guest machine and view them in the host machine. So port 80 is the only concern. However, even ping doesn't work.

What else should I check?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: check if your `/etc/network/interfaces` haves this lines `auto eth0` `iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Comment: @FranciscoTapia No. But the networking works fine except for the connection between the host and the guest. Will adding the line make difference?

Comment: As a workaround, I set up 2 connections. One for host-only and the other for bridged. Now I got what I want. But I still don't understand why the problem occurred.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with VB 5.04 on a Windows 7 host with both Windows 8.1 and 10 in a VM. Both 8.1 and 10 can see the internet, can see my networked printer, can see my phone but can't se the Win 7 host. Win 7 host can see both 8.1 and 10 but when trying to connect I get "Can't Find Machine XXX".

I uninstalled VB 5.x and reinstalled VB 4.30 along with downgrading the guest additions and now everything is back to normal. Host can see and connect to VMs and VMs can see and connect to host. Something in VB 5.x is blocking host connections.